# Is an hypersurface uniquely determined by an equation?

Tags: differential-geometry

Consider $r:\Omega\to\Bbb R$ suffiently regular, $\Omega\subseteq\Bbb C^n$, $z_0\in\Omega$ s.t. $r(z_0)=0$.
Then $r=0$ defines an hypersurface locally around $0$.

My question is: is $r$ unique?

By unique, I mean that if $g$ is another function which vanishes in $z_0$, is possible that $g=0$ defines the same hypersurface around $z_0$? Obviously $g=cr$, for $c\in\Bbb R$ is ok, so I don't take it in account. But are there other possibilities?

Comment: The answer is no, or else, you would have only one possible surface.

Comment: Yeah you're right. Thanks man

Comment: Well, $r^3=0$ defines the same hypersurface locally around $z_0$. As it does $r(z)(\|z\|^2+1)=0$...